# const object or private/const data members (variables) in C++?

Tags: c++

We know that `const` object members cannot be modified once declared but what is the real use of them? We can individually declare variables to be `const` inside the class or declare them `private`.

If there is any other significance of **const object in C++**, then please mention that too.

Comment: With the keyword const, you can assure the variable have the same value for all execution of the program

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo:not necessarily - a `const` type can bind to a non-`const` type.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking exactly. Are you asking why you would declare an object as `const` rather than declaring all members of the object/class as `const` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba: "Binding" would be references, not variables. But you can have const references as members, so that might belong in an answer.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo: No, that's wrong. `const` variables don't change their value during their lifetime, but a `const` variable local to a recursive function can even have different values at the same time (!). That's because each function that has been called an not yet returned has its own copy, so the lifetimes stack.

Comment: Since my answer is considered to be a little off, maybe OP can clarify. To me it seems the question was primarily about const members vs private members in a class. With a bonus for info constness in C++ in general. Is that correct?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question literally:

If you make members of a class `const`, that applies to every instance of the class, but only to the members that you made `const`.

If you make an object `const`, that applies to a single instance of that class, but it does apply to all members of that instance.

Comment: You answered my downside. That was great clarification between single and all instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`const` is one of the most elementary subjects in C++, in my opinion. Something that is way too often overlooked.

Generally `const` has three use cases:

- Allowing the compiler to optimize more aggressively
- Allowing the compiler to point out our mistakes when we accidentally try to change a const value
- Convey intend by specifying that we do not want an object changed

In the case of a const member of a class, we force the object to be initialized during instantiation of the class. Preventing us from accidentally changing it's value in member functions. Which is the big difference to just using a private member variable. We still can accidentally change a private member variable anywhere inside the class.

One of the most useful ways to use const is with parameters:

- This can allow major optimization for the compiler, for various reasons that are out of scope of this answer.
- And in the case of const references, the compiler can prevent you from accidentally changing the value of that reference.
- Most importantly, it allows you to define the signature of your function in a more clarifying way.

Comment: It is not possible to change a non-mutable private member in a member function that is specified as `const`.    Also, a `const` member can have `mutable` members, and they can be changed.

Comment: @Peter: That's factually incorrect. That restriction only applies to modifications directly via `this`. If you have an `int*` to an `int` member, you can still change that `int` member. This restricts possible compiler optimizations.

Comment: @Peter That is generally true. But I didn't talk about non-mutable private members. Or const member functions for that matter. Nor mutable members of const objects. I tried to keep my answer to the point and on the same level of the asked question.

Answer (score 1):

I luckily use this once(so far). And i never thought i would need to use a `const` in a member variable.

```
class TypeA {
protected:
    DataX const* m_data;        //get a pointer to a data that shouldn't be modified even inside the class.
public:
    TypeA(DataX const* p){
        m_data = p;
    }
    auto& getData(){ return *m_data; }   //will return DataX const&
}
```

For the `private` member variables, i think they are best for helper-variables in the current class that are really not part of the object logically. Maybe for caching, temporary holder of some data that should be there for a time duration, a counter for an algorithm, etc. And they are only used and should be used in the current class. You don't want other programmers to use them in the derived class because they have a very special use so you hide them in `private`.

Another example for `const` member are for constant values aside for `enum`s. I prefer enum over a variable that takes storage but some programmer prefer following on what they used to however you convinced them not to(maybe i'm wrong, and they are really correct, and maybe in the future for some reason the `const` in the language changed, and then using `const` might be better.)

```
class TypeA {
public:
     const int HEY_VALUE = 101;
     const int YOH_VALUE = 102;
     const int HELP_VALUE = 911;
     const float MIN_SOMETHING = 0.01;
     static const int HELLO_EARTH = 10;
     //...

}
```

I can't find this specific code of mine, but i think i used `&` instead of `const*`. I used it like this.

```
class TypeA {
protected:
    DataX& m_data;        
public:
    TypeA(DataX& p):m_data(p){   //you can only set this once in the constructor

    }
    auto& getData(){ return m_data; }   //will return DataX const&
}
```

I really prefer using `.` instead of `->` for personal reasons so I really pushing myself to achieve the syntax i want and i came with these weird solutions. It's fun because I discovered that those weird approaches are still valid and achievable in c++.

---

**Update**

> If there is any other significance of const object in C++, then please mention that too.

Maybe you can `const` some filler bytes on specific part of the class.

```
class TypeA {
protected:
     const int HEADER_BYTES = 0x00616263;
     int m_data1;
     int m_data2;
     const uint8_t ANOTHER_FILLER_FOR_SOME_REASON = 0xffffffff; //maybe forcing offset address, or alignment, etc.
     int m_anotherData;
}
```

Comment: That's not a `const` member, though. It's a non-const member which gives read-only access to a `DataX` object.

Comment: @MSalters yeah, it's really not the exact answer for OP's question but i thought it's fun sharing my experience where i used a `const` in a member variable. it amazed me at that time i used that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `const` keyword is being used to improve readability of the code you are writing.

However, in some cases `const` can also allow compiler optimizations. Let's see the following code snippet:

```
int const i = 1;
fun(&i);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Here, trying to modify the variable `i` would cause an Undefined Behaviour. Therefore, the compiler will assume modification won't be even tried so it will pass the value `1` to the `printf` function.

Same is valid for const data members.